# Starting JBoss as non-superuser (root) on Linux

Tags: linux, jboss

Is it possible to start JBoss as a non-root user? 
I have tried this and it fails due to permission issues on critical directories. 
Do I have have to create a special group permission for JBoss to do something like this? 
Or do I have to use some other workarounds to launch as something other than superuser? 
Will applications deploy properly without the JBoss service running as su?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the best approach is to introduce a new user and new group for this process that has the required permissions.

Regards,
Sascha